# How sparse does a matrix need to be to be worth representing as sparse?

Tags: r, memory, matrix, sparse-matrix

In R, I'm trying to work with a large matrix (39,146,166 rows by 127 columns) and I'm having memory issues with a number of operations on it. I've determined that about 35% of the entries in the matrix are non-zero, and the remainder are all zeros. Is this sparse enough that I would save some memory representing this matrix using one of R's sparse matrix classes? What is a good rule of thumb for determining when a matrix is worth representing sparsely?

Comment: You may find [this article](http://www.johnmyleswhite.com/notebook/2011/10/31/using-sparse-matrices-in-r/) helpful.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think the sparse representation will be that much more compact. You need three numbers for each numeric item other than an implicit zero. So even if two of those are 4 byte integers the space in memory will still be larger than a "serial" storage strategy.

By this reasoning anything above 50% will take more storage space, but I'm posting from an iPhone under SF Bay so cannot test with 'object.size'.

Comment: There are a number of sparse matrix formats, and not all of them require 3 numbers per nonzero entry. For example, this format requires about 2 for my case: http://netlib.org/linalg/html_templates/node92.html

Comment: @RyanThompson: That format requires 3 vectors, not two

Comment: Only two of those vectors have an entry for each data point. The last vector only has one element for each column, which is negligible in my case.

Comment: And if that were any of the representations in the R Matrix package then you could use it as a basis for estimation. But as far as I can tell neither the T-matrix nor the C-matrix versions use such a method.